# Vue Create - Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...2","standard-version"'

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

When I run `vue create app1`, I got this error in the error log:

```
2733 silly saveTree `-- @vue/cli-service@4.5.8
2734 verbose stack SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...2","standard-version"'
2734 verbose stack     at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
2734 verbose stack     at parseJson (C:\Users\findi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\json-parse-better-errors\index.js:7:17)
2734 verbose stack     at C:\Users\findi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-fetch-npm\src\body.js:96:50
2734 verbose stack     at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
2734 verbose stack     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
2735 verbose cwd C:\vue\app
2736 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19041
2737 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\findi\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "--loglevel" "error"
2738 verbose node v12.18.3
2739 verbose npm  v6.14.8
2740 error Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...2","standard-version"'
2741 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: Can you try running `npm cache clean --force` as admin in your terminal?

Comment: It works. Error no more. Thanks.

Comment: @Kickin_Wing could you turn that into an answer so it can be accepted?

Comment: @micpap25 it's entered as an answer now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try running `npm cache clean --force` to clear out npm's cache